# When will the deprecated Twitter API version 1 be disabled?

Tags: rest, twitter, deprecated

According to [Twitter API FAQ](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/faq),

> REST API version 1 is now deprecated and will cease functioning in
>   March 2013. Move to version 1.1 as soon as possible. The concept of
>   "version 1" of the API includes unversioned APIs like the Search API.

However, at the moment it is still working. For example, you can still [search for tweets](http://json-indent.appspot.com/indent?url=http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stack%2boverflow&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed&rpp=200). Will the legacy API finally cease working, and if it will, when will that happen?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find a specific answer to this question. Basically, they can take it down at any moment without any warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API v1 will be retired on June 11th 2013.

Full details at the link below:

https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-retirement-date-extended-to-june-11